# STLPort 5.2.1 throwing compiling errors when built in Visual studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

We are using STL port 5.2.1 in our project which we are upgarding from VS 2008 to VS 2017, So trying to compile STL port also on VS 2017 , but its throwing below errors:

```
stlport-5.2.1\stlport\errno.h(35): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'MSVCINCLUDEC/ucrt/errno.h': No such file or directory
stlport-5.2.1\stlport\assert.h(30): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'MSVCINCLUDEC/ucrt/assert.h': No such file or directory
```

Looking for solution for these errors, if anyone knows please let me know.

Comment: Honestly, forget about STLPort and simply use the STL that is already in VS 2017.  STLPort was for those compilers that had limited support for STL, mostly Borland compilers back 10+ years ago (more closer to 20 years than 10 years).  That is no longer the case in this day and age of C++.

Comment: Also, even in VS 2008, what was the reason for using STLPort in that compiler?  Even that compiler had good enough, if not close to standard STL support without usage of any third-party code.  Looks like you were holding onto a dinosaur for no reason.

Comment: You've got into trouble by not updating your tools and frameworks when you should have. Now you are going to perpetuate that problem by only partially updating. Since you are updating, bite the bullet and update everything.

Comment: @OP I would be relieved not having to support something old as STLPort, and now instead have access to using a modern, up-to-date (almost, since there is VS 2019) version of STL.  I would just nuke the STLPort directory (or remove it completely from your project), compile the code, fix the compiler errors, replace any non-standard STL with standard STL.  That would probably take far less time than fighting with a library that is obsolete.

Comment: We are not using STL port directly. dbaccess which we are using is building this STL port internally.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, We are actually using dbaccess which internally building this STL Port

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie or @ john , please let me know if you have any pointers from where i can get latest dbaccess code so that we need not depend on STL port anymore

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that STLPort is obsolete.  What would happen if you simply removed STLPort?  Then dbaccess would have no choice but to either use the STL that is already available, or you make (more than likely, minor) changes to the dbaccess source to use the current STL.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzieThanks for the suggestion will try to remove support of STL port (dn't know how hard it is) and use current STL

Comment: @Pavan: The observation still stands. If that `dbaccess` library is still using STLport, then it's likely that `dbaccess` is no longer actively maintained. If you can't get an updated version of `dbaccess`, you should look into a replacement library.

Comment: @Pavan,  If you're ambitious, it *may* be as simple as just removing the STLPort files and directory.  Then either dbaccess will "automatically" use the vector, list, map, etc. classes that come with VS2017 and will compile with no errors, or if there are errors, more than likely simple to address.  But a better decision would be to get an update to dbaccess or get another db library.

Comment: Unfortunately, STLPort has stopped developing since version 5.21 in 2008 and can not  support C++11.  So, I think updating dbaccess or getting another db library will be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions, i removed STLPort in dbaccess and with slight changes in code it automatically picked latest STL and it worked

Comment: @Pavan -- See how simple that was?  As long as dbaccess used the same STL interface, it should work with the latest version that is provided by the compiler.